# Angular 2 + CLI : Error in Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, angular-cli

I have a problem with my Ng2 project for 3 - 4 days.

#### Versions.

- @angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.2
- node: 6.9.2
- os: win32 x64
- @angular/common: 2.4.9
- @angular/compiler: 2.4.9
- @angular/core: 2.4.9
- @angular/forms: 2.4.9
- @angular/http: 2.4.9
- @angular/platform-browser: 2.4.9
- @angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.9
- @angular/router: 3.4.9
- @angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.2
- @angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.9

#### Repro steps.

I run ng serv / ng test or ng build and i have : "ERROR in Maximum call stack size exceeded"

#### The log given by the failure.

After "ng serve"

```
$ ng serve
** NG Live Development Server is running on http://localhost:4200 **
Hash: a73c4ecdb8222366629e
Time: 16536ms
chunk    {0} polyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map (polyfills) 405 kB {5} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {1} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 41.1 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {2} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js.map (styles) 149 kB {5} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {3} scripts.bundle.js, scripts.bundle.js.map (scripts) 244 kB {5} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {4} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js.map (vendor) 2.75 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {5} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map (inline) 0 bytes [entry] [rendered]

ERROR in Maximum call stack size exceeded
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

After I save one time and all is alright :

```
$ ng serve
** NG Live Development Server is running on http://localhost:4200 **
Hash: a73c4ecdb8222366629e
Time: 16536ms
chunk    {0} polyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map (polyfills) 405 kB {5} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {1} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 41.1 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {2} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js.map (styles) 149 kB {5} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {3} scripts.bundle.js, scripts.bundle.js.map (scripts) 244 kB {5} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {4} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js.map (vendor) 2.75 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {5} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map (inline) 0 bytes [entry] [rendered]

ERROR in Maximum call stack size exceeded
webpack: Failed to compile.
webpack: Compiling...
Hash: 02fd7618c3e2de3db52e
Time: 9915ms
chunk    {0} 0.chunk.js, 0.chunk.js.map 926 kB {1} {2} {3} {5} [rendered]
chunk    {1} 1.chunk.js, 1.chunk.js.map 397 kB {0} {2} {3} {5} [rendered]
chunk    {2} 2.chunk.js, 2.chunk.js.map 33.1 kB {0} {1} {3} {5} [rendered]
chunk    {3} 3.chunk.js, 3.chunk.js.map 2.96 kB {0} {1} {2} {5} [rendered]
chunk    {4} polyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map (polyfills) 405 kB {9} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {5} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 41.1 kB {8} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {6} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js.map (styles) 149 kB {9} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {7} scripts.bundle.js, scripts.bundle.js.map (scripts) 244 kB {9} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {8} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js.map (vendor) 2.75 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {9} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map (inline) 0 bytes [entry] [rendered]
webpack: Compiled successfully.
```

And for "ng test" is same.

Any idea to resolve this ?

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I met with the same error. **Solved by deleting unnecessary imports**.

Cause of this error you have **circular module dependency** problem.

> **For example:**
>
> 'A' module imports (dependent to)  'B' module
>
> 'B' module  imports (dependent to) 'A' module

I suggest you to **build a common module** that other modules should import the common module.

If you have unnecessary imports **delete unnecessary imports**.

Comment: I can build a common module in case where I have to use shared components, pipes or directives, what if I want to load a module containing routes as well?
check out below SO question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43907450/angular-2-circular-feature-module-dependency

Answer (score 22):

The best way i found to debug this is :

```
ng serve --aot
```

It will exit building if any error is found with an understandable error.

Comment: To me, this resulted in the same error message.

Answer (score 5):

If you getter (or a method) returns itself you will get circular reference resulting in Maximum call stack size exceeded exception.
Ex.

```
public get test(): any {
    return test;
```

}

Review your code for that.

Answer (score 2):

In my case this happen when trying to call the selector of its own component (Kind of circular dependency).

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue.I forgot to import my feature router module to feature module, so i got the above error. hope it helps others..

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the `node_modules` folder, then running `npm install` and `ng serve` again did the trick for me.

Got the tip from here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/17106

Answer (score 0):

In my case I put a component in the wrong sub-module.  Kind of a cryptic error for a misplaced componnet.  For example:

```
src
|-account
    |-account.modue.ts
|-admin
    |-admin.module.ts
    |-users
        |-user-maintenance.component.ts


account.module.ts
   ...
   @NgModule({
       declarations: [
           UserMaintenanceComponent   // this should be in admin.module.ts
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error due to circular dependency of modules import.

A -> B, B -> A,

I have solved this just by removing A from B and added to app.module.ts.

Answer (score -1):

When I have got an

> Error in maximum call stack exceeded

**Resolved using following command:**

```
ng build --prod --base-href "PATH OF SERVER" --aot=false --build-optimizer=false
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation of why you did this and how it fixed the issue?