# ERROR in Maximum call stack size exceeded after updating angular 9 to 10

Tags: angular

I read the update instructions in Angular website to update version from 9 to 10 (because I can't from 9 to 11) and everything was fine until I typed ng serve in the terminal to launch the webapp and it appears this message 'ERROR in Maximum call stack size exceeded
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ ** '

When I open the browser on localhost:4200 the page is blank.

Here my dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@amcharts/amcharts4": "4.7.8",
    "@amcharts/amcharts4-geodata": "4.1.8",
    "@angular/animations": "^10.2.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "^10.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^10.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "^10.2.5",
    "@angular/forms": "^10.2.5",
    "@angular/material": "^10.2.7",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^10.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^10.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^10.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "^10.2.5",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^10.2.5",
    "@kolkov/angular-editor": "^1.1.2",
    "@material/layout-grid": "^7.0.0",
    "@ngrx/core": "^1.2.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^10.1.2",
    "@ngrx/store": "^10.1.2",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^12.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^18.0.1",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "export-to-csv": "^0.2.1",
    "export-to-csv-file": "^0.2.2",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "flag-icon-css": "^3.4.6",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ngx-clipboard": "^12.3.1",
    "ngx-gravatar": "^8.1.0",
    "ngx-permissions": "^7.0.3",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "xlsx": "^0.16.9",
    "zone.js": "^0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1002.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^10.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^10.2.5",
    "@angular/language-service": "^10.2.5",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.11",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^13.7.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.6.2",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.0"
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2 + CLI : Error in Maximum call stack size exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42811049/angular-2-cli-error-in-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded)

Comment: Any error in the console?

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete node_modules and install packages again. this should be help you as reported here https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/17106